# How do I represent complex Map as parameter argument for Class.declaredMethod parameterType?

Tags: java, junit, reflection

I have a private method I need to access from a junit. The method has the following signature:

```
private String search(Map<String, String[]> params, String userName)
```

I have tried the following setup:

```
Method mockSearch;
Class[] cArg = new Class[2];

cArg[0] = Map<String, String[]>.class  
cArg[1] = String.class;
mockSearch = aClass.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("search", cArg);
```

Which obviously won't even compile because "cArg[0] = Map<String, String[]>.class" is nonsensical. So I attempted a concrete class for arg 0 like this:

```
Map<String, String[]> mockMap = new HashMap<>();
cArg[0] = mockMap.getClass();
```

which threw exception at runtime because of the strictness of the getDeclaredMethod. Here basically is exception snippet:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: blah.blah.blah$MyTestClass.search(java.util.HashMap, java.lang.String)
```

Is there a way to represent a Map<String, String[]> class type that will work? Thanks for ideas.

Comment: `cArg[0] = Map.class;` You have to use raw class literals with reflection APIs, but there's no risk of ambiguity because you can't have two methods with the same erased signature.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks, but that does not work either: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: blah.blah$MyTestClass.search(java.util.Map, java.lang.String)

Comment: Are you sure that `aClass` is the right class? It's hard to tell it wouldn't be working without a [mcve].

Comment: @AndyTurner, yes I am. Its literally (no obscured code) the line at the beginning of my post: "private String search(Map<String, String[]> params, String userName) "

Comment: I'm with Andy, this should just work. Please provide a [mcve] (and full stack traces).

Comment: thank you. I stand corrected. @AndyTurner solution worked. I have some other issue between my junit and and original class with the the private method (which is outside scope of this post) but Andy's solution was correct and i validated with following simplified implementation:

Comment: import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestDeclaredMethodIssue {


    private String search(Map<String, String[]> params, String userName) {
        return "a string";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method mockSearch;
        Class[] cArg = new Class[2];
        cArg[0] = Map.class;
        cArg[1] = String.class;
        Class c = TestDeclaredMethodIssue.class;
        mockSearch = c.getDeclaredMethod("search", cArg);
        mockSearch.setAccessible(true);
    }
}

Comment: How do I give Andy credit for the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
cArg[0] = Map.class;
```

You have to use raw class literals with reflection APIs, but there's no risk of ambiguity because you can't have two methods with the same erased signature.